# Xcode 6.1 titleTextAttributes

Tags: swift, xcode6

so I am writing this app that has colorful navigationbars and the font of the title in that bars and the font of the UIBarButtonItems should be white and in a specific font. I used these 2 lines to accomplish that in the AppDelegate..

```
    UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = [NSFontAttributeName : UIFont(name: "SourceSansPro-Regular", size: 22), NSForegroundColorAttributeName : UIColor.whiteColor()]
UIBarButtonItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([NSFontAttributeName : UIFont(name: "SourceSansPro-Regular", size: 22), NSForegroundColorAttributeName : UIColor.whiteColor()], forState: .Normal)
```

But with Xcode 6.1 I get an error in each of these lines and I really don't know, what in means..

[image]

The text attributes are [NSObject: AnyObject]?. That's exactly what I wrote down.. Does anybody has a solution for this?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

I think the problem is because they've changed `UIFont`'s initializer in 6.1 so it can return `nil`. That is correct behavior because if you enter wrong font name there is no way to instantiate `UIFont`. In this case your dictionary becomes `[NSObject: AnyObject?]` which is not the same with `[NSObject: AnyObject]`. You can first initialize fonts and then you can use `if let` syntax. Here is how to do this

```
let font = UIFont(name: "SourceSansPro-Regular", size: 22)
if let font = font {
    UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = [NSFontAttributeName : font, NSForegroundColorAttributeName : UIColor.whiteColor()]
}
```

Or if you sure the font object is not gonna be `nil` you can use implicitly unwrapped optional syntax. In this case you are taking the risk of runtime crash. Here is how to do it.

```
UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = [NSFontAttributeName : UIFont(name: "SourceSansPro-Regular", size: 22)!, NSForegroundColorAttributeName : UIColor.whiteColor()]
```

Comment: Yes, that's it! Thank you very much. I think it's very confusing that a initialisier can return nil but it makes sense.. :)